# Why didn't Esther bring a nose with her to the party?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Esther invites the king and Haman to a party. Haman returns home from the party and calls his wife and his loved ones and says (Esther 5):

> אף לא הביאה אסתר המלכה עם המלך אל המשתה אשר עשתה...
>
> Esther did not bring a nose with her and the king to the party that
> she made ..

A few questions (please answer as many as you can):

- Was Haman expecting a specific nose belonging to someone, or any nose? Whose nose?
- Why was Hman expecting Esther to bring a nose to the party?
- Why didn't Esther bring a nose?
- (Related to previous Q) If Esther was trying to upset Haman, it would be understandable for her NOT to bring a nose. But, Haman was happy that she forgot the nose. So, what was behind Esther's thinking?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: That explains how come after Haman got the bucket of manure on his head he wasn't in a rush to shower himself.

Answer (score 2):

Esther's Hebrew name was Hadassah, which is like hadassim in a lulav. The hadassim are pleasant looking and smell nice, but they do not taste good. 
Esther was called Hadassah because she "smelled" and looked pleasant to the Jews. But to Haman she did not "taste" good. Thus, she did not bring a nose with her, because it might have sniffed her out as a Jew and given away her scheme.

(Courtesy of my sister)

Answer (score 2):

Haman was pleased that Esther did not bring her nose because then he knew she lacked the means to have him pursued him and destroyed in the future, which would require her nose. 
(Eicha 3:66  תִּרְדֹף בְּאַף וְתַשְׁמִידֵם מִתַּחַת שְׁמֵי ה) [No nose, no destruction]

What he didn't know, and she did, is that she was confident she could get another day out of the king (another party, or another day to take revenge) or, a day named for her by the **K**ing (=Ta'anit Esther). And if so:   כִּי לְךָ הַיוֹם אַף לְךָ לַּיְלָה, if you get a day, it's as if you had a nose that night.

Answer (score 1):

You cut off the pasuk too early.

> וַיֹּאמֶר הָמָן אַף לֹא הֵבִיאָה אֶסְתֵּר הַמַּלְכָּה עִם הַמֶּלֶךְ
>   אֶל הַמִּשְׁתֶּה אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂתָה כִּי אִם אוֹתִי

Haman said, the queen did not bring a nose with the king to the feast that she made except for me.

That is, she only provided a "nose" (a person who is expert at blending scents) in order to make the feast even more pleasant *for me*. Haman thought that she was honoring him by setting up an even more elaborate feast than she would have done for the king himself. He did not realize that this was really to get the king to realize *something is rotten here* by having someone who could detect the subtle odor of treachery emanating from Haman and warn the king.

Answer (score 1):

She didn't want Haman to complete his quintet of destruction.

[Why did Haman lack Af?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69095)