# PTIJ: Why is Vashti referred to in the plural in Megillat Rut?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Towards the beginning of Megillat Rut (1:7), we discover that Vashti played a central role in Naomi's return to Eretz Yisrael:

> ותצא מן המקום אשר היתה שמה ושתי כלתיה עמה ותלכנה בדרך לשוב אל ארץ יהודה
>
> And she left from the place in which she was, Vashti her daughters-in-law with her, and they walked on the path to return to the land of Yehuda.

However, the verse remains unclear: why is Vashti referred to in the plural, as daughters-in-law?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't get it. Vashti isn't being referred to in the plural here. The daughters-in-law are. :/

Comment: @ezra Umm yeah, it's Purim Torah for a reason... sheesh.

Comment: @ezra https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26584/what-are-the-consequences-of-vashti-s-dual-nature

Answer (score 5):

Vashti is referred to in the plural as [she was gene engineered from two women](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26584/what-are-the-consequences-of-vashti-s-dual-nature) as it says in the megilla.

> גַּם וַשְׁתִּ֣י הַמַּלְכָּ֔ה עָֽשְׂתָ֖ה מִשְׁתֵּ֣ה נָשִׁ֑ים
>
> And Vashti was made from two women.

Vashti was actually a gilgul of Orpah so that the navi is hinting that just as Orpah failed the test of abandoning idol worship to follow Naomi, Vashti also was given a chance to repent and recover and failed the test.

**Note** we can see this because of the name which means *two*. Perhaps we can say that she was a combination of parts of Rus and Orpah. That is, the part of Rus that she discarded when she converted and became a giyores was combined with part of Orpah to make the *doubled* Vashti.

Comment: Riddle: What were Vashti's mothers' names?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26595/4794

Comment: @רבותמחשבות the names of Achashverosh's two mothers-in-law:   חמת המלך שככה and חמתו בערה בו