# PTIJ: Cloning capability in Persia

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Where do we see in Megillas Esther that ancient Persia had advanced medical technology. They could even do things that we cannot accomplish.

How did Achashveiros develop such advanced technology and how did it become lost?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Missed it by _that_ much...

Comment: @DoubleAA Technically, the entire month of Adar should be allowed for PTIJ. Also, there are minhagim to celebrate on the 16th and 17th as well as Purim and Shushan Purim. In fact the shiur that I go to had a seudah today. There are those who do not say tachanun on the 16th and 17th.

Comment: @sabba technically, the policy allows for whatever it says. If you want to change it, post on Meta.

Comment: Isn't this a riddle, disqualified even as Purim Torah on this site?

Comment: As we see from the answer, it is Purim Torah from the megillah. @user6591

Answer (score 1):

We see in megillas Esther that the Persian Empire had advance cloning capability. As it says

> גַּם וַשְׁתִּ֣י הַמַּלְכָּ֔ה עָֽשְׂתָ֖ה מִשְׁתֵּ֣ה נָשִׁ֑ים
>
> And Vashti was made from two women.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26584/759